# ext-all-debug.js:106054 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: extjs

I encountered this bug but it comes from `Ext Js 5.0.0.970`, and here is the trace:

```
ext-all-debug.js:106054 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
Ext.view.AbstractView#appendNodes @ ext-all-debug.js:106054
Ext.view.AbstractView#doAdd @ ext-all-debug.js:106067
Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer#onRangeFetched @ ext-all-debug.js:150576
Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer#onRangeFetched @ ext-all-debug.js:150642
Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer#renderRange @ ext-all-debug.js:150485
Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer#handleViewScroll @ ext-all-debug.js:150395
Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer#onViewScroll @ ext-all-debug.js:150333
Ext.util.Event#fire @ ext-all-debug.js:21840
Ext.util.Observable#doFireEvent @ ext-all-debug.js:22282
prototype.doFireEvent @ ext-all-debug.js:85478
Ext.util.Observable#fireEventArgs @ ext-all-debug.js:22260
Ext.util.Observable#fireEvent @ ext-all-debug.js:22232
Ext.view.AbstractView#onViewScroll @ ext-all-debug.js:105838
Ext.Base#callParent @ ext-all-debug.js:7606
Ext.view.Table#onViewScroll @ ext-all-debug.js:108556
(anonymous function) @ ext-all-debug.js:4416
```

It happens when I scroll a table which is a Ext.grid.Panel, of 200 rows, and it doesn't stop me from viewing the table, just errors in console. It's difficult to put my codes here because it's big and I don't know which part causes the problem.

Can anyone help me to guess what could be the reason or where should I start looking?

Thanks.

Comment: Please download the newest bugfix release (5.0.3) for your ExtJS version and check whether it has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Although I can't find 5.0.3, bug updating to 5.0.1 solved the problem, thanks!